# Javascript Append Textarea value issue

Tags: javascript, append

I have created four textarea boxes and I would like to get their values when I click the submit button. When I click the submit button I would like to append the text, that it was written in the textareas after the submit button as plain text. I have tried to `createElement("p")` and append the values but it's not working. Here is what I have done until now. Anyone can help me to find what the problem is?

Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content-container">
    <label>First Content<label>
      <textarea id="fisrt-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Second Content<label>
      <textarea id="second-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Third Content<label>
      <textarea id="third-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Fourth Content<label>
      <textarea id="fourth-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>


      <button id="c-btn">Submit</button>

      <div id ="c-content"></div> 

</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var firstContent = document.getElementById("first-content");
var secondContent = document.getElementById("second-content");
var thirdContent = document.getElementById("third-content");
var fourthContent = document.getElementById("fourth-content");
var customContainer = document.getElementById("c-content");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("c-btn");


function submitCustomForm() {

  var cElementOne = document.createElement("p");
cElementOne = firstContent.value;
customContainer.append(cElementOne);

  var cElementTwo = document.createElement("p");
cElementTwo = secondContent.value;
customContainer.append(cElementTwo);

  var cElementThree = document.createElement("p");
cElementThree = thirdContent.value;
customContainer.append(cElementThree);

  var cElementFour = document.createElement("p");
cElementFour = fourthContent.value;
customContainer.append(cElementFour);
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitCustomForm);
```

Comment: You have a typo in your html: id="fisrt-content". Also, as suggested in answer, don't rewrite vars: https://jsfiddle.net/ozmw0pgd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cElementOne = firstContent.value;` - this rewrites your variable

Try this code

```
var cElementOne = document.createElement("p");
cElementOne.innerText = firstContent.value;
customContainer.appendChild(cElementOne);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that also but its not working.

Comment: Also you have: "fisrt-content" as textarea id and `getElementById("first-content")`

Answer (score 0):

Id if first text area is not correct as per your JavaScript code.

**--Incorrect one**  fisrt-content

`textarea id="**fisrt**-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>`

--Correct ID  first-content
`<textarea id="first-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>`

enjoy

Below is correct code working for me and also make sure to run it on google chrome first then try in other browsers, as seems addeventlister not supported by internet explorer:

HTML

```
 ` <div class="content-container">
    <label>First Content<label>
      <textarea id="first-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert 
      Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Second Content<label>
      <textarea id="second-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert   
      Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Third Content<label>
      <textarea id="third-content" class="content-area" placeholder="Insert 
       Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <label>Fourth Content<label>
         <textarea id="fourth-content" class="content-area"      
     placeholder="Insert        Content Here"></textarea>
      </div>


      <button id="c-btn" name="c-btn">Submit</button>

      <div id ="c-content"></div> 

   </div>`


`<script type="text/javascript">
var firstContent = document.getElementById("first-content");
var secondContent = document.getElementById("second-content");
var thirdContent = document.getElementById("third-content");
var fourthContent = document.getElementById("fourth-content");
var customContainer = document.getElementById("c-content");
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("c-btn");


    function submitCustomForm() {

    var cElementOne = document.createElement("p");
    cElementOne = firstContent.value;
    customContainer.append(cElementOne);

    var cElementTwo = document.createElement("p");
    cElementTwo = firstContent.value;
    customContainer.append(cElementTwo);

    var cElementThree = document.createElement("p");
    cElementThree = firstContent.value;
    customContainer.append(cElementThree);

    var cElementFour = document.createElement("p");
    cElementFour = firstContent.value;
    customContainer.append(cElementFour);
    }

    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitCustomForm);
    </script>`
```

Sudeep Patel